# how to jump in a server using putty

Tags: putty, tunneling

I am facing a situation:
From my Local Machine (LM) I connect in a VPN using OpenVPN (HTZ) then I am able to use putty to connect into a HTZ server (lets call it server X). From that server X I have access to another server (lets call this Y) on port 443 and 80.

The problem is: i have to access a web service in this server Y using my chrome or whatever i have in my LM to access a web gui.

How do I build the tunnels to jump from my LM to server Y with this server X (which is the only one i have access from my LM)?

[]'s

Answer (score 1):

Open putty, create a session to your server X, click on connection -> SSH -> Tunnels.

At "Add new fordwared port" enter 1080 and set the options to Dynamic/Auto. Save the session and connect to X. Putty will now act as a local SOCKS(5) proxy and listen at 1080(tcp).

Open your browser and in network settings configure it to use a SOCKS proxy. Enter 127.0.0.1 as IP address and 1080 as port. From now on your browser connections will use the putty tunnel and you can reach anything that is reachable by server X.

If you don't want to switch SOCKS on/off every time you want to tunnel your connections, use a second browser or a different browser identity.

Comment: Let me go a little further: i am using vmware horizon client too. I already edit internet options but I receiving a message: couldn`t resolve proxy name. Do you know how to fix it?